# How do I get VS code extension to run my code correctly?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Vs code version 1.48.2, and I have an extension to run my programs, but when I run it, it gives me a name error: Name is not defined.  I've tried running it in repl it and have no problems.This is the error:
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'rears' is not defined

Comment: Can you paste to code and the name of the extension you are using

Comment: you may have to define a launch config to properly set the current directory, etc that your program expects to be run with.

Comment: read the docs of VSC on how to run Python scripts, and a bit of code would help. The only thing we know is that the identifier `rears` is on line 1. Not even the character position.

Comment: @J_soza Have you ever tried to run this script in the cmd window? Can it be run successfully there? It will be better resolved if you could provide more relevant information.